# Drupal node.tpl doesn't apply changement to contact form page

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

New in Drupal Theming, I've a code where node.tpl file is updated (changed) but the contact page doesn't take the modifications. Any help would be appreciate.

In the node.tpl file, somebody add this code :

```
<?php 

 include('includes/right_menu.inc');

?>
```

Ok, it seems not logical but...

I see this include in any node page excepted for contact page.

Had I to make a specific node--contact.tpl.php or other ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, the contact page is not displaying a node, but a form. Therefore, the `node.tpl` template file is not used in this context.

Comment: OK. If I can't use node.tpl which solutions do I have ? If I use page-contact.tpl, I cannot reuse the "include". I know that the code is not logical, it would have been easier to use blocks on  rightSidebar I think.

Comment: I agree with you that using a block seems to be the most standard solution. Otherwise, you might have the same problem when displaying other entities which are not nodes (taxonomies, for instance).